# Class that is loosely coupled from its properties of Stream type in TDD

Tags: c#, tdd

I want to write a class that uses properties of stream type via TDD. The class will open/write file from/to file system. like below:

```
 public class Csv 
    {         
        private TextReader streamReader; //TextReader is an abstract class, parent of streamReader 
        private TextWriter streamWriter;  //similar to TextReader and StreamWriter
          //Read(), Write(), and other methods that are specific to CSV.
        }
```

It is testable now.

The problem is that I want it to support either read or write for each instance, not both. Because Csv supports either read or write not both.

Another problem, caller of the class should provide fileName only.

Third problem, ideally, it should have an Open(string fileName). But it may not be necessary.

Comment: Your question is hard to answer, since you haven't explained why it wasn't testable before. But if you want to be able to test the class against different inputs and check the output, then yes this seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: The class will open/write file from/to file system. Please see my update.

Comment: Your implementation follows TDD if it facilitates writing the tests you want against it. That is more or less it. If you only show your prod code I can only make a rough assessment. But my answer still stands, your design has the advantage that it is testable without having to create files, which simplifies testing.

Comment: But the Csv class supports either read or write not both. The current constructor seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create your `CsvReader`, `CvsWriter` class which takes `IStream` interfaces as constuctor parameter, following Dependency Injection principles (just like you mentioned above).

As the tests ready and code ready, you create a small wrappers which now take a file names are constructor/method parameters. No need to test it, since it's nothing more as just opening stream and delegating functionality to already tested code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution and it is testable with TDD. you can use Moq to do unit testing.

```
public class Csv : IReader, IWriter
{
    protected Stream Stream = null;
    public string IsReader;
    private StreamWriter writer = null;
    private StreamReader reader = null;
    public Csv(string fileName)
    {
        Stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    }


    public StreamWriter SrWriter
    {
        get
        {
            if (reader == null)
            {
                writer = new StreamWriter(Stream);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Current stream type is reader");
            }

            return writer;
        }
    }

    public StreamReader SrReader
    {
        get
        {
            if (writer == null)
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(Stream);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Current stream type is writer");
            }

            return reader;
        }
    }
}

    public interface IReader
    {
        StreamReader SrReader { get; }
    }
    public interface IWriter
    {
        StreamWriter SrWriter { get; }
    }
```

Comment: The class also has methods, e.g. Read() and Write() that are specific to CSV.

Comment: you can use methods instead of properties. This was my personal prefference